# C++ Headers files and class definitions issue

Tags: c++

**Question:** I have delcared a class, then used in my main function, it throws undefined error. Then I added .h file, and it throws another error. My question is about to write .h in accordance with the .cpp class file. Here are details:

I have this class declated in ElevatorButton.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class ElevatorButton
{
    public:
        int pressed = 0; // boolean

        void myFunc(int param1)
        {
            cout << param1 << endl;
        }
};
```

And then I have this file in ElevatorSimulation.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    ElevatorButton ElvBtn;

    cout << ElvBtn.myFunc(1) << endl;
}
```

Compiling the code regularly throws error. I should declare header file as it seems. But in my header file, how should I manage the definition? I have read about .h file but still am confused. Here is my header.cpp:

```
#ifndef ElevatorButton_H
#define ElevatorButton_H

class ElevatorButton
{
public:
    int pressed = 0; // boolean
public:
    void myFunc(int param1){};
};

#endif
```

But it throws the following error with the Header.h:

```
1>ElevatorSimulation.cpp(14): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: Sometimes simply reading the error message (Kudos for including it) is enough. ... Not quite right, more often than not.

Comment: `header.cpp` sounds pretty wrong :P ...

Answer (score 3):

You're getting that error because `myFunc` returns void, so

```
cout << ElvBtn.myFunc(1)
```

doesn't have a definition when the right hand side evaluates to void. If you want to print a value with `cout`, `myFunc` will have to return a type that can be passed into a stream.

The issue isn't with your class definition at all, it's in your main function.

Answer (score 0):

Is it header.cpp? Because it should be header.h